# How to change the content of a div without reloading the webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website, that uses PHP to select the content,

```
<div>  
    <? include ("navigation.php"); // navigation.php generates the menu ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?      
        $type = $_GET["type"];
        switch ($type) {
        case "page" :
            include "Text.php";
            break;  
        case "news":
            include "news_2.php";
            break;
        default :
            include "main.php";     
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The url is of the format `domain.com/index.php?type`.
I need to change the block `#content` without reloading the whole page, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

As you've tagged the question with "jquery" I assume you know what that is, and that you're loading it into your page.

All you need to is give your div and ID... content here

And then use a bit of jquery.. in its simplest form just to load your content from 'myurl.php' into 'mydiv' when the page has finished loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#mydiv").load("myurl.php");
});
```

You'll no doubt want some logic to determine what loads, and under what circumstances.  If you need to pass data back to the URL then you'll need to go for jquery ajax ($.ajax).  Its all pretty easy, loads of examples on the web, and good docs on the JQuery website.

Answer (score 1):

This would best be done with Ajax. I like using jQuery's ajax function. Something like this:

```
function load(page){    
    var datastring='ANY DATA YOU WANT TO SEND';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'your/pagehtml/',
        data: "bust="+Date()+datastring,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){ 
            $('#content').html(html)
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

You wouldn't need to send the page in the URL this way. Anytime you change the url, you must be loading a different page. Outside of .htaccess rewrite. Which isn't what you need.

Fire this on click or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, it's pretty easy. You didn't post what is supposed to trigger the change, so I'll assume you have a list of links in another element with an id of nav.

Read more about the jQuery Ajax request here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
//run on page load
$(function(){   
    //bind a click event to the nav links
    $("#nav a").bind("click", function(e){ 

        //keep the links from going to another page by preventing their default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //this = link; grab the url
        var pageLocation = this.href;

        //fire off an ajax request
        $.ajax({ 
            url: pageLocation, 

            //on success, set the html to the responsetext
            success: function(data){ 
                $("#content").html(data.responseText); 
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

I'd also suggest doing some code cleanup like caching your $("#content") element on the load event (something like window.container = $("#container"), and using window.container later on), but I left it as-is so that everything remains clear.

Comment: thank you very much but what if i'm getting the content from a mysql query in another file and this uses the _get method i dont know how to do this

Comment: You can pass in data using something like the example here: http://pastebin.com/vGUZ6XrM. If you have the querystring on the url you're passing in, it should pass them on and do a get properly without having to define the data separately like in that example.